# TypeScriptでAPIから返ってきたオブジェクトの配列に型を定義したい

Tags: typescript

下記のURLにアクセスするとGitHubリポジトリのデータがJsonファイルで返されるのですが、配列の中に複数オブジェクトが入ってる物にどのように型を定義すれば良いか教えて頂けないでしょうか？
https://api.github.com/repositories/354726603/contents/articles

この記事を参考に出来ると思ったのですが、返ってくるデータが`[{},{},{}...]`となっていて返ってくる数も今後増える予想です。
そうなった際にどのように型を定義したら良いか分からなくなりました。
どうか助けて頂けないでしょうか？お願いします。

[fetchの結果に型を付けたい](https://zenn.dev/uzimaru0000/articles/json-type-validation)

```
type Articles = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  created_at: number;
  updated_at: number;
};
```

Comment: `> 業務ではどのように書いてているのか教えて頂けると幸いです。` この質問だとただのアンケートになってしまうので、書かれた型で何か具体的に発生している問題があれば、それを質問して頂いた方が良いかと思います。(追記で書かれた方が主題であれば、それが分かるように編集された方が良いかもしれません)

Comment: すいません。質問を分けて書くことにしました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75252/typescript%e3%81%a7%e5%ae%9a%e7%be%a9%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e5%9e%8b%e3%82%92%e5%86%8d%e5%88%a9%e7%94%a8%e5%87%ba%e6%9d%a5%e3%82%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%abapi-d-ts%e3%81%ab%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6import%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84

Answer (score 1):

自分なりに書いてみた。 `Article` という型定義を書いてそれが配列になっているというイメージで書きました。
これで型定義自体は出来たと思います。

```
type Article = {
  name: string;
  sha: string;
  size: number;
  url: string;
  html_url: string;
  git_url: string;
  download_url: string;
  type: string;
  _links: {
    self: string;
    git: string;
    html: string;
  }
};

const zennArticles: Article[] = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/wimpykid719/zenn-content/contents/articles/")
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```