# TypeScriptで定義した型を再利用出来るようにapi.d.tsに書いてimportしたい。

Tags: typescript

下記のコードを参考に

```
declare module 'foo' {
  export val bar: number;
}
```

型の再利用を出来るようにしたくて、ルートに `@types/api.d.ts` とファイルを作成してそこに下記のようにして記述したのですが、 `module` にあたるものをどう書いて良いか分からないです。教えて頂けないでしょうか？ `export`の位置もおかしい気がします。

```
export declare type Article = {
  name: string;
  sha: string;
  size: number;
  url: string;
  html_url: string;
  git_url: string;
  download_url: string;
  type: string;
  _links: {
    self: string;
    git: string;
    html: string;
  }
};
```

**呼び出し側**

```
import { Article } from '../@types/api'
```

#### 参照

[TypeScriptの型: 既存の JavaScript ライブラリに型情報を追加する（.d.ts ファイル）](https://maku.blog/p/s7wk5k3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. TypeScriptを使用しているプロジェクトで、型Aliasを複数のファイルで使用したい場合**

型Aliasはexport可能ですので、exportして再利用してください。

**Article.ts**

```
export type Article = {
  ...
}
```

**Foo.ts**

```
import { Article } from "./Article";

const article: Article = ...
```

**2. あなたがJavaScriptライブラリを開発中で、そのライブラリの為の型定義ファイルを同梱して提供したい場合**

参照されているリンクのタイトルにも書かれていますが、`module`(.d.tsファイル)はJavaScriptライブラリをTypeScriptで利用するためのものです。

TypeScript の型定義ファイルと仲良くなろう - Hatena Developer Blog
https://developer.hatenastaff.com/entry/2016/06/27/140931#module

この場合、JavaScriptライブラリを公開(参照)する際のモジュール名があるはずですので、その名前のmoduleないしnamespaceを`declare`で定義します。

例えばmoment.jsの場合は `moment` になります。

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.29.1/package.json#L27

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.29.1/moment.d.ts#L19

これにより、TypeScriptでmomentをimportした際にこのライブラリの型定義が自動で参照され、TypeScriptで利用可能になります。

**Foo.ts**

```
import moment from 'moment';

moment().format();
```

moduleとnamespaceの使い分けですが、ごくごく簡単に言うとWebアプリケーションで`<script>`タグ内で全ての依存が解決されるようなライブラリの場合は`namespace`で良いです(例:`react`や`moment`)。

これに該当しない場合やNode.jsでの使用が前提の場合は`module`を使用してください。

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#using-modules

> Namespaces can be a good way to structure your code in a Web Application, with all dependencies included as `<script>` tags in your HTML page.

Comment: 毎回ドキュメント先まで、ありがとうございます。とても助かります。